# What is a good way of getting a (significant) part of several minion's pillar from a single yaml file?

Tags: salt-stack

Imagine that we have a single yaml file that describes roles of users in variety of systems. it may look like this:

```
username:
   systemA:
      - roleA
      - roleB
   systemB:
      - roleC
```

I would like to use this file a source for all the minions to populate the list of users and roles for their respective systems. So the minion of systemA would have only this in it's pillar:

```
username:
   - roleA
   - roleB
```

I'm not sure that I want to make it kinda default pillar and rip parts out of it depending on the minion using jinja. But other options, like regenerating pillars using python from this file on every change or storing this data in DB and using ext_pillar, looks even worse to me. But may be I'm just don't see something obvious.
Thanks!

Comment: Why does this information need to be in a pillar in the first place? User roles aren't usually secret.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User roles aren't usually secret, so this doesn't need any transformation, and it doesn't need to be in pillars in the first place.

Simply lookup using the current minion id (or whatever "systemA" is) in your states and/or map.jinja:

```
{% set roles = data["username"][grains["id"]] %}
```